# Apply Snazzy maps to MX Google Maps

Tags: mx-google-map

I want to apply a [snazzymap](https://snazzymaps.com/) to MX Google Maps.

Comment: Hey Seb, thanks for sharing this info! Snazzy Maps is very cool. It would be best if you add your share in the QA format. To do that just rewrite your "question" as a question and then post the code share as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Thanks, Seb. In 48 hours you can [accept your own answer.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Max's MX Google Map [1.5.3] for publish form maps and wish to apply a [snazzymap](https://snazzymaps.com/) you can do so by adding the snazzymap styles on line 496 of system/third_party/mx_google_map/ft.mx_google_map.php.

Download the snazzymap you want to apply. View the source. Copy from:

```
// How you would like to style the map. 
// This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
    styles: ... ]}]
```

And then paste it just after:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#'.$randid.'_map").mxgoogleMaps({
    latitude: '.$data["latitude"].',
    longitude: '.$data["longitude"].',
    zoom:  '.$zoom.',
    markers: ['.$markers.'],
```

So it looks something like this:

```
   [...]
   markers: ['.$markers.'],

   // Snazzy maps hackery
   styles: [{"featureType":"landscape","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":65},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":51},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":30},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":40},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"transit","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.province","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":-25},{"saturation":-100}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#ffff00"},{"lightness":-25},{"saturation":-97}]}],
   // End Snazzy maps hackery

   field_id : "'.$randid.'"
   [...]
```

Remember to add a comma after the closing square bracket `]}],`.